# Equivalent type for CMapStringToString in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++-cli

I need to write a .NET Managed wrapper for C++ function defined as follows:

```
void getMap(CMapStringToString*& Map);
```

This function stores in the necessary information in the Map variable.

Now I wrapped the function as follows but I somehow do not get the correct output from the wrapped function:

```
void GetMap(System::Collections::Specialized::StringDictionary ^% nMap)
{
  CMapStringToString orig_map, *map = &orig_map, *&mapRef = map;
  m_pUnmanagedObject->getMap(mapRef);
  for(POSITION pos = orig_map.GetStartPosition(); pos != NULL; )
  {
    CString key, pa, &paRef = pa;
    orig_map.GetNextAssoc(pos, key, paRef);
    nMap->Add(gcnew System::String((LPCTSTR)key), gcnew System::String((LPCTSTR)pa));
  }
}
```

There is definitely something wrong with the wrapper because when I use the C++ code I get the correct output but when I use the wrapper code, the *nMap* is empty (i.e. in C# when I did *nMap.Count*, it returned 0 whereas for that same example in C++ I was getting 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
orig_map.GetStartPosition()
```

and

```
orig_map.GetNextAssoc(...
```

with

```
(*mapRef).GetStartPosition()
```

and

```
(*mapRef).GetNextAssoc(...
```